# Not getting ID (it's undefined) of created record in redux-saga in React-admin

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga, react-admin

This is the problem.
I wanted to catch ID of newly created record so I created custom watcher saga that listens to every "RA/CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS". And my worker saga needs to get ID of newly created record so I can do second call to other endpoint using that ID, with some other data.

But for some reason every time the record is created, watcher saga does indeed work, but the ID of that record is undefined in payload. Everything else is there except the ID.

I am using simple form, and creating record just like they explain in documentation. 
I am using react-admin ver. 2.9.7

Any suggestions, ideas, fixes are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to source, both on 2.9.7,

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.9.7/packages/ra-core/src/actions/dataActions/crudCreate.ts#L86

and

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/v2.9.7/packages/ra-core/src/types.ts#L7

The id should be there, on action.payload.id. Since it's not, either is a react-admin bug, which you can try changing the version to fix, or your dataProvider not returning the id of created resources, but with that, react-admin probably would complain and you would have already noticied the error, and after creating, if redirect="edit", you would be redirect to /resource/undefined. This happen?

If this a ra bug, you can try to extract id from action.meta.redirectTo, if it's there, or, not using sagas at all, intercept dataProvider requests, and everytime a CREATE request succeds, do your second call:

```
import { CREATE } from 'react-admin'

const interceptorDataProvider = dataProvider = async (verb, resource, params) => {
     if (verb === CREATE) {

         let response

         try {
             response = await dataProvider(verb, resource, params)
         } catch (e) {
             return Promise.reject(e)//ra expects rejecteds promises
         }

         //do your second call with response.data.id
         return response             

     }

    return dataProvider(verb, resource, params)
}
```

Comment: The record gets created fine, after the creation I can see it in the list component, it has the ID also. So the creation process regarding record is working.
But I have noticed that dataprovider gets called twice for creation and I am not sure why is that happening. The first time it is called it returns everything except ID, but the next time it's called, POST request contains the correct data with the ID. 
This is really strange behaviour and it would be good to find the problem.
And yes, I was also starting to think about ditching the sagas and, and intercept the dataProvider request.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue, it was in dataprovider. I fixed it and now it works okay. 
With sagas, and also if you intercept dataProvider with async/await.